# Read json and parse

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I was looking for the answer on my isseu  :

I want to read an JSON file and parse it in a tableview like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/14eDq.png 
This is not the problem but when a user taps the UITableCell i want to display the whole message like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx2TK.png

What is the best way to do that? Could somebody push me to the right way?

I just want to display the message and load the images etcetra

Comment: Can you make the question more specific? What exactly are you having trouble with? Is it moving from the table view to a detail view, or rendering your content in the detail view, or something else? Are you using storyboards or no? If JSON isn't part of the question, why mention it?

Comment: I want to move a table view to a detail view

Comment: Okay, keep going... *You want to move from a table to a detail view **but** you don't know how to _______?* Push a new view controller onto the navigation stack? Use storyboard segues? Create a new view controller? Detect taps on table cells? [Read example code?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007323-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of frameworks to parse JSON data out there. I used [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse my data. Then create an array to hold a part of your data(generate array from the response dictionary, mean JSON dictionary). After that define a title for each row of the tableview and on the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{}
```

delegate method push a new view to display the details of that title's subject. If you need more help please write down